# Strange ASP.NET GridView SortExpression behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a C# , ASP.NET 4.5 , WebFrom app.

The issue I have is as soon as I specify the `SortExpression` .

The HeaderText does not show up anymore.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Services" SortExpression="ServiceName"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Wrap="True">
   <ItemStyle Wrap="true" HorizontalAlign="center" />
       <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceName") %>' runat="server" ID="lbSName" />
  </ItemTemplate>
 <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlServices" AutoPostBack="False" CssClass="DropDownList" runat="server" DataSource="<%# dvAllServices  %>" DataTextField="ServiceName" EnableViewState="True" DataValueField="ID" OnPreRender="SetDefaultListItem" />
  </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: The code you posted probably has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: If I remove SortExpression="ServiceName" Header Text becomes visible.

Comment: Then it's probably a css thing. When there is a sort expression the header becomes an anchor. Maybe look at the html and see if it actually rendered.